# Ag-Grid DOM of row

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to get a DOM element of the row in ag-grid?

```
 this.gridOptions.api.getRowNode(id)
```

This way can get the object of a row. But how to get the DOM of this row?

Comment: could you extend the details, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to add eventListener "dragover" to the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution:

```
constructor(public myElement: ElementRef) { }

this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
  ...
};

ngAfterViewInit() { 
    const countOfRows = this.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount(); 
    for (let i = 0; i < countOfRows; i++) {
      const elements = this.myElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(`[row-index="${i}"]`);
      const row = elements[1];
      row.addEventListener('dragover', function() {
        row.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      });
    }
}
```